# Следует ли избегать связь "многие-ко-многим"

Tags: база-данных

Слышал, что отношение "многие-ко-многим" следует избегать и сводить его к "один-ко-многим". Правда ли это? И почему следует так делать?

Comment: А вы бы не могли привести пример, как связь многие-ко-многим можно свести к связи один-ко-многим. Потому как все связи м-м, которые приходят мне в голову  по другому выразить невозможно. И где вы кстати прочитали такую глупость ? Может они хотят сказать что не следует городить м-м там где ей в принципе не место ?

Comment: Например, есть таблицы `sites` и `filter_rules` (сайты, которые нужно спарсить, и правила фильтрации путей, которые можно парсить, что-то типа robots.txt). Вариант многие-ко-многим: у каждого сайта может быть несколько правил фильтрации, и наоборот. Появляется третья таблица `sites_filter_rules`. Вариант один-ко-многим: в таблице с правилами появляется колонка site_id. И если два сайта используют одно и то же правило, то это правило дублируется в таблице, различаются у них только колонка `site_id`.

Comment: В этой ситуации я бы исходил из того откуда появляются правила и как используются. Если правила вводит человек и ему удобно просто набирать их из справочника и они часто дублируются - то м-м. Если правила автоматом создаются на основе чтения robots.txt, то о-м. Хотя и в этом случае может м-м ввел для уменьшения объема таблицы. Как по мне, раз в robots.txt пути и они задаются на каждом сайте независимо - то о-м больше походит на жизнь. А если мы сами руками заносим кучу доп. инфы в записи и она повторяется, то делая о-м мы вносим в БД избыточность, что ведет к опечаткам на вводе

Answer (score 1):

Наверное имеется ввиду что, когда, например, у вас есть таблица статей и таблица тегов, то:

- Неправильно будет добавить в таблицу статей дополнительные колонки для некоторого числа тегов вида `ID тега 1`, `ID тега 2`, `ID тега 3`
- Правильно будет создать ещё одну таблицу вида `ID связи` - `ID статьи` - `ID тега`

Почему именно так легко увидеть попытавшись сделать поиск по тегам в том и другом случае.